# Java: SecretKey to String and rebuilding back to SecretKey produces different decryption result

Tags: java, cryptography, secret-key

Currently i've created a SecretKey for use in a RC4 encryption for my assignment. After the RC4 encryption i would then convert this key into string and send it to a server via UDP however when i rebuild it on the server side using SecretKeySpec, it would produce a completely different secret key.
I've looked around stackoverflow for solutions but the end would still result in a rebuilt SecretKey being different from my original SecretKey.

I've tried rebuilding the Secret Key from the String format on the client code and the result would still be a different SecretKey compared to the original so i doubt my UDP tranmission has anything to do with the result.

Below are how i went about creating the initial SecretKey for use in a RC4 encryption:

```
KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
SecretKey originalSecretKey = keygen.generateKey();
```

How i converted the SecretKey to String and rebuilt using SecretKeySpec:

```
String k = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalSecretKey.getEncoded());
byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(k);
SecretKey rebuiltSK = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "RC4");
```

When I println "originalSecretKey" and "rebuiltSK" for checking, this is where I realised the rebuilt values are completely different and therefore i wouldnt be able to decrypt any originalSecretKey-encrypted message using the rebuiltSK.

*Edit1*: Silly me, thank you to "A Developer" and "Daniel" for pointing out that the actual .getEncoded() values of "originalSecretKey" and "rebuiltSK" are the same.

Apologies if I'm missing something extremely basic regarding Key generation and java's cryptography as this is my first time using them. Thank you in advance for your help !

Edit2:
Below is the code i'm currently using for my RC4 encryption and decryption:

```
public static byte[] encryptRC4(byte[] b, SecretKey k) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
//Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE when on server program
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(b);
        return encrypted;
    }
```

The code above is the reason why I'm trying to rebuild the secretKey on the server end after receiving it in byte[] from the client.

I've tried running the decryption with the "rebuiltSK" as the SecretKey argument however it doesn't produce the correct plaintext although I've checked the packet.getData() on both client and server to be the same.

Comment: "therefore I wouldn't be able to decrypt": did you actually try it? The key may just be represented differently.

Comment: How do you say the rebuiltSK is different from orginalSecretKey? If you just to println with object, it'll be different because both are different objects but the value will be same. If you check the encoded value in the key like rebuiltSK.getEncoded() it will be same as of originalSecretKey.getEncoded()

Comment: @Adeveloper that's what I got as well, an exact byte-for-byte representation of `originalSecretKey.key` and `rebuiltSK.key`. The only difference between these two objects is the `.algorithm` which was `RC4` for `rebuiltSK` and `ARCFOUR` for `originalSecretKey`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you omitted some context? I tried your snippet of code and it works as intended for me. Has `k` been transmitted and garbled, perhaps?

Comment: ***Why?*** `String` is not a container for binary data. You should be using a byte array for the key. That's how you get it, that's how you use it, that's how you should pass it around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rebuilding of the SecretKey works like expected and the encryption followed by the decryption retrieves the
original plaintext.

I can only that argue (same as @Daniel) that the key was changed during transmission or the (byte[] with the)
ciphertext was not fully transmitted to the server.

The below full example code shows a complete round with key generation, encryption and decryption.

This is the result:

```
plaintext equals decryptedtext: true
decryptedtext: my secret
```

**Security warning: The code below uses an UNSECURE algorithm 'RC4' or 'ARCFOUR'.
Please do not copy below code or use it in production - it is for educasional purposes only.
The code does not have any proper exception handling !**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63185927/java-secretkey-to-string-and-rebuilding-back-to-secretkey-produces-different-de");
        // security warning: the algorithm 'RC4' or 'ARCFOUR' is unsecure and
        // should be used for educational purposes only
        // do not use this code in production
        // key generation
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
        SecretKey originalSecretKey = keygen.generateKey();
        // encryption
        byte[] plaintext = "my secret".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] ciphertext = encryptRC4(plaintext, originalSecretKey);
        // decryption
        String k = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalSecretKey.getEncoded());
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(k);
        SecretKey rebuiltSK = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "RC4");
        byte[] decryptedtext = decryptRC4(ciphertext, rebuiltSK);
        // output
        System.out.println("plaintext equals decryptedtext: " + Arrays.equals(plaintext, decryptedtext));
        System.out.println("decryptedtext: " + new String(decryptedtext));
    }

    public static byte[] encryptRC4(byte[] b, SecretKey k) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(b);
        return encrypted;
    }
    public static byte[] decryptRC4(byte[] b, SecretKey k) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(b);
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Before i would rebuild my secret key using 
"SecretKey rebuiltSK = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length,  "RC4");" based on another question's recommended answer but after using yours, everything just worked.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that my solution (that is still unsecure) worked for. Can you kindly mark my answer as accepted? Thanks.